# Regex to read till end of line - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string,
`a = abc:nd10!<>)($` 
and I would like to split the string using regex into to parts,
`part 1=abc`
`part 2=nd10!<>)($`

I could do the following
`([\w]+):([\w\!\<\>\(\)\$]*)`
but this restricts me to the special characters I've explicitly mentioned, rather I want to fix this in such a way that it reads till the end of line.

Please do not recommend splitting the string via a delimiter etc, I want to solve this issue using regex only. The reason I want to use regex is because my actual string is way more complicated than the one mentioned above but I put the simple one to not over complicate the issue.

Comment: Why not simply split on `:` character ? can the second part contain `:` ?

Comment: *Why* do you want to solve this using regex? You seem to be describing a simple str.split.

Comment: I mentioned this in my question, I want to use regex only, the reason for this is, my problem is more compilcated than mentioned but I gave the simple example as above as to not overcomplicate the question. I've edited my question to answer your question.

Comment: Could you provide more than a vague description? What does *"more complicated"* actually mean? Note that a [mcve] needs to recreate the problem, there's no point simplifying so far that the solutions don't meet your real needs.

Comment: My question was straight forward, I need to solve my problem using regex, anyhow, I'll update my question with the actual string

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just replace this:
    [\w!\<>()\$]
With a period:
    .

A period matches anything

Comment: This doesnt work, I tried it here: https://regex101.com/r/b3vZOS/1

Comment: @asmijkun you did not. The brackets are still there. Take them out.

Comment: I said to replace the whole thing not just the stuff in the brackets.

Comment: Facepalm. Now you removed the * for some reason. Just go here: https://regex101.com/r/b3vZOS/2